# How to setup ESLint in VSCode to work with every project?

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

Below is the process I am doing in VSCode to setup for every project I create:

1. run command `npm init` from project folder and this is creating `package.json` file.
2. Run the command `eslint --init` and it asks bunch of questions about modules, framwork etc and it creates `eslintrc.json` file.

If I don't do these steps, every time I open a js(helper.js or controller.js files) file, it shows error message at the bottom right corner saying ESLint configuration not found.

Is there a easy way of doing this so that it works with every project that I create in VSCode?

**EDIT**:

- VSCode version: 1.35.0
- Salesforce Extension Pack: 45.15.1
- Output of command `sfdx --version`

> sfdx-cli/7.8.1-8f830784cc darwin-x64 node-v10.15.3

Comment: Is this specifically in regards to DX, or VS Code in general?

Comment: I have Salesforce DX extension installed and creating project using the option `Create project with manifest`.

Comment: Are you on the latest version of VS Code, the Salesforce DX Bundle, and SFDX? Try updating all of them and see if that makes a difference. I know that older versions of the bundle didn't seem to work right, but I haven't had an eslint error in a while.

Comment: @sfdcfox I think I am using everything latest. Updated question with version details.

Comment: Hmm, okay, I think I'm out of ideas. Sorry . All I know is that it works for me, when I load a project it creates a .vscode/settings.json, and eslint is already configured there. In fact, it's a custom lwc version in `c:\\Users\\brian\\.vscode\\extensions\\salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-lwc-45.15.1\\node_modules`. I presume if everything is working correctly, the file should already be there. The only other suggestion I have would be to uninstall and reinstall VS Code and/or all your extensions to see if that fixes it.